# RabbitTemplate is not configured as MessageListener

Tags: spring-amqp

I need to send and receive an ack synchronously and for that I am using the RabbitTemplate.

The RabbitTemplate has queue and replyAddress property, but when trying to send me this error appears:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: RabbitTemplate is not configured as
>   MessageListener - can not use a 'replyAddress':
>   amq.gen-t1ESvGc4I8EfGJCjWjBxKw

If I use the Send method instead of SendAndReceive then the process is correct but the response arrives asynchronously to me (I have a MessageListener for that), but is not not what I need.

Is it possible that I can not use the same response queue for RabbitTemplate that I have for the MessageListener?

---

Thank you again Gary, and sorry because the question is really not clear.

I have a MessageListener working correctly when I send a message, but for some messages I need a synchronous reply. When I use the sendAndReceive method, I get the exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: RabbitTemplate is not configured as MessageListener - can not use a 'replyAddress': amq.gen-t1ESvGc4I8EfGJCjWjBxKw

And the RabbitTemplate has the property replyAddress : amq.gen-t1ESvGc4I8EfGJCjWjBxKw

If I use the method send, then the response arrives asynchronous to the MessageListener. But I need a synchronous response for some messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear; if you want a synchronous reply then use sendAndReceive; the calling thread will block until the reply is received.

No, you can't use the same queue as the listener - they will compete for messages.

If you want async send and receive, the `replyToAddress` can only be used with `sendAndReceive` operations.

If you want to do async send and receive, you have to set the `replyTo` property (queue name or `exchange/routingKey`) in the message properties - before calling `send` or in a `MessagePostProcessor` when using `sendAndReceive`.

You need to configure a listener container to receive the replies (which you said you have).

The upcoming [1.6 release](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/16/spring-amqp-1-6-0-milestone-1-and-1-5-4-available) has an `AsyncRabbitTemplate` that has `sendAndReceive` methods that return a `ListenableFuture`; it's a convenience that wraps a `RabbitTemplate` and `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` for replies.

**EDIT**

You can't use the same reply queue for sync and async replies.

When using a fixed reply queue, you need to [configure a reply listener container as described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#reply-listener).

However, you don't really need to specify a reply queue; the template will use [Direct ReplyTo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#direct-reply-to) if the broker supports it (or a temporary queue otherwise).

If you must use a named reply queue (e.g. you need HA or the responding system doesn't use the replyTo property), then you must configure a reply listener (with the template being the listener).

Comment: I added more information to the question. Asynchronous reply is working properly, the problem is when I expect a synchronous response.